# Visual Studio doesn't reset tests results

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest

I am on Visual Studio 2015 and I am using MsTest.

If I open Visual Studio "first time" after Windows boot, I can see all test results empty, I can right click and choose "Run all tests" and they run.

After first run, if I re-compile the solution the test results are not wipe out and when I run a test it looks like it is using the "old code" after my modifications.
If I right click a test and choose "debug test" then it starts to use the latest changes...

It happens on my PC but on TFS everything is fine. It started to happen after I installed VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

to get around it, i just unload/reload the test project, and it should reset the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Test results are not cleared after a build.  I've never experienced a situation where tests were run against old code after a new build.  Are you sure this is happening?

Comment: Yes. Me neither, now after a build all previous results are still there, which is very odd.

Comment: Previous test results have never cleared after a build for me.

Comment: If I do clean then tests are removed, before it was enough to rebuild without choosing clean

Comment: I have opposite problem. After VS 2015 restart i have all test results are wiped. Which is unexpected because i can't leave job half-way done...Why is that happening? Some incorrect settings?

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes occurs due to an error in the test engine. I had a similar problem, and I went to the *Output* window, then selected *Tests*. The output helped me get a hint about the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 solution bellow

- Right click your test project, then "clean"
- Delete .sln file and restart vs (when something go wrong with my solution, this option always work with me)

Answer (score 0):

For me (on VS2017) I have to restart the whole VS. Closing the project/solution is insufficient. Thankfully I don't need to rebuild though.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio, solution explorer

Right-click on your solution "ProjectName" -> Clean solution.